# Understand rank-one operators in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $\{e_n \}$ be an orthonormal basis on a Hilbert space $H$. When we say that $T$ is a rank-one operator, it means that the range of $T$ has dimension $1$. Then for example, would $Te_n=e_n$ be of rank-one?

I think it's not of rank-one, since in this case we could have $Tx=x$ for $x\in H$. So the range is just $H$, so it doesn't see to be of rank-one.

So in that case would all rank-one operators be constants?

Could I get some examples of rank-one operators?

Thank you!

Comment: non-zero constants do not define _linear_ operators. A typical rank-one operator might be the projection onto a one-dimensional subspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to say in general what a rank-one operator on Hilbert space looks like. Suppose that $T$ is rank-one. So $\dim TH=1$. Let $y\in TH$ be nonzero. Then, for any $x\in H$,
$$
Tx=\lambda_xy
$$
for some $\lambda_x\in\mathbb C$. It is not hard to check that the map $x\longmapsto\lambda_x$ is linear and bounded; by the Riesz Representation Theorem, there exists $z\in H$ with $\lambda_x=\langle x,z\rangle$. So
$$
Tx=\langle x,z\rangle\,y.
$$
For some concrete examples, any rank-one matrix $A\in M_n(\mathbb C)$ gives you an example of a rank-one operator on $\mathbb C^n$.